# Convert sql join query to laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, join

```
SELECT school_courses.*, schools.school_name, schools.country, schools.city  FROM 
school_courses JOIN schools ON school_courses.school_id = schools.id
```

Hello there,

I want to convert the above SQL query to laravel.
And also I want to learn joins in laravel query please share any easy step by step tutorial link if you have one.

Comment: If you really want to _learn_ how to do this, then the best thing would be to attempt to write a solution in Laravel and then include that in your question.  As for tutorial sites, the official documentation already does a good job of explaining joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Query Builder way of doing it.

```
   $result = DB::table('school_courses')
         ->join('schools','schools.id','=','school_courses.school_id')
         ->select('school_courses.*','schools.school_name', 'schools.country', 'schools.city')
         ->get();
```

Refer this link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

Comment: Thank you! for your quick response. I will refer to this link.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use better Eloquent: Relationships

[Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Your converted query is given below

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$users = DB::table('school_courses')
         ->join('schools', 'us schools ers.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
         ->select('school_courses.*','schools.school_name', 'schools.country', 'schools.city')
         ->get();
```